# How to get the Intel UHD Graphics 605 i915 videocard working with Vulkan?

Tags: video-processing, video-capture, image-recognition, hardware-acceleration

i have an Intel UHD Graphics 605 (i915) and i want to use it with Vulkan/ncnn.

The information from this site is, that Vulkan should work with version 1.1.103:
https://technical.city/de/video/UHD-Graphics-605

My vulkaninfo tells me:
Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.131

Could anybody help me with experience?

Does Ubuntu have the correct driver for the graphic card? I don’t know how to get this info.
Does Vulkan use the GPU for ncnn (https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn) ?

My system:
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=5a1d628672